# How to make a function return a pointer to a function? (C++)

Tags: c++, return-value, function-pointers

I'm trying to make a function that takes a character, then returns a pointer to a function depending on what the character was.  I just am not sure how to make a function return a pointer to a function.

Comment: Will the signature of the returned function always be the same?

Comment: Here's the signature of a function that takes a function pointer and returns one: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f1() {
    return 1;
}

int f2() {
    return 2;
}

typedef int (*fptr)();


fptr f( char c ) {
    if ( c == '1' ) {
        return f1;
    }
    else {
        return f2;
    }
}

int main() {
    char c = '1';
    fptr fp = f( c );
    cout << fp() << endl;
}
```

Comment: I am wondering why this works. Shouldn't we deference the function pointer first,
i.e. `cout << (*fp)() << endl;` ?

Comment: @qed: No. You can dereference it, but it's perfectly ok not to do it. Usual function are already pointer internally anyway.

Comment: To @qed and anyone else who stumbles upon this and has the same question: I had a similar question. See the summary of the answer in the bottom of my question here: [C++ Function call via an object with public member pointer to function, without using dereference operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31869026/4561887). Whether you do  `myFuncPtr();`, `(*myFuncPtr)();`, `(**myFuncPtr)();`, or even `(**********************************f)();`, it makes no difference. They are all valid function calls.

Answer (score 107):

```
int f(char) {
    return 0;
}

int (*return_f())(char) {
    return f;
}
```

No, seriously, use a typedef :)

Comment: @Axalo The program compiles as is. ```return_f``` does not take any arguments but returns a function that takes a char.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "use a typedef"?

Comment: provide a shortcut `typedef int (*ifc)(char);` and use it as the return type in your function: `ifc return_f();`

Answer (score 20):

Create a typedef for the function signature:

```
typedef void (* FuncSig)(int param);
```

Then declare your function as returning FuncSig:

```
FuncSig GetFunction();
```

Answer (score 14):

Assuming `int f(char)` and `ret_f` which returns `&f`.

C++98/C++03 compatible ways:

- Ugly way:

  ```
  int (*ret_f()) (char) { return &f; }
  ```
- With typedef:

  ```
  typedef int (sig)(char);

  sig* ret_f() { return &f; }
  ```

  or:

  ```
  typedef int (*sig_ptr)(char);

  sig_ptr ret_f() { return &f; }
  ```

Since C++11, in addition we have:

- with [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

  ```
  decltype(&f) ret_f() { return &f; }
  ```
- trailing return type:

  ```
  auto ret_f() -> int(*)(char) { return &f; }
  ```

  or:

  ```
  auto ret_f() -> decltype(&f) { return &f; }
  ```
- `typedef` with `using`:

  ```
  using sig = int(char);

  sig* ret_f() { return &f; }
  ```

  or:

  ```
  using sig_ptr = int (*)(char);

  sig_ptr ret_f() { return &f; }
  ```

C++14 adds:

- `auto` deduction:

  ```
  auto ret_f() { return &f; }
  ```

Comment: A "developers reference answer", clear and straight to the point!

Answer (score 10):

In C++11 you can use trailing return types to simplify the syntax, e.g. assuming a function:

```
int c(int d) { return d * 2; }
```

This can be returned from a function (that takes a double to show that):

```
int (*foo(double e))(int)
{
    e;
    return c;
}
```

Using a trailing return type, this becomes a bit easier to read:

```
auto foo2(double e) -> int(*)(int)
{
    e;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Super helpful!

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to do it without using a typedef:

```
int c(){ return 0; }

int (* foo (void))(){  //compiles
return c;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Syntax for returning the function:**

```
return_type_of_returning_function (*function_name_which_returns_function)(actual_function_parameters) (returning_function_parameters)
```

Eg:
Consider the function that need to be returned as follows,

```
void* (iNeedToBeReturend)(double iNeedToBeReturend_par)
{
}
```

Now the iNeedToBeReturend function can be returned as

```
void* (*iAmGoingToReturn(int iAmGoingToReturn_par))(double)
{
   return iNeedToBeReturend;
}
```

I Felt very bad to learn this concept after 3 years of professional programming life.

Bonus for you waiting down for dereferencing function pointer.

[C++ Interview questions](http://www.arraynotfound.com/2016/07/cpp-interview-questions-and-answers-from-freshers-to-experienced.html#Q_4_1_2)

Example for function which returns the function pointer is
[dlopen in dynamic library in c++](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef void (*voidFn)();

void foo()
{
}

voidFn goo(char c)
{
    if (c == 'f') {
        return foo;
    }
    else {
        //..
    }
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the code to show return of a function pointer. You need to define the "function signature" to return first:

```
int returnsOne() {
     return 1;
}

typedef int(*fp)();

fp returnsFPtoReturnsOne() {
    &returnsOne;
}
```

In your specific case:

```
fp getFunctionFor(char code) {
    switch (code) {
        case 'a': return &functionA;
        case 'b': return &functionB;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this site - http://cdecl.org

Helps you convert english to C declarations and back!

Cool Stuff!

This link decodes the example in erikallen's answer.
[int (*return_f())(char)](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%20%28%2areturn_f%28%29%29%28char%29)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to typedef the pointer-to-function type you want, and then use that

```
typedef void (*fnptr_t)(int, int);
fptr_t myfunc(char *) { ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer returning objects and call the operator().  This way your function can return an interface and all classes can inherit from this.  That is, if you're using C++ and not C.

Then you can use the parametrized factor method to return the objects based on your input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming C here (no objects) :) :

```
// Type of function which takes a char and returns an int:
typedef int (*Func)(char a);

// An example of the function you're trying to return and which does something
// with char:
int exampleFunc(char a)
{
    return (int)(a + 42);
}

// The function returning the pointer to a function:
Func *returnAfunc(void)
{
    return exampleFunc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
#include <iostream>

typedef char (*fn_ptr_t)(char);

char a_fn(char c)
{
  return c + 1;
}

char b_fn(char c)
{
  return c + 2;
}

fn_ptr_t
return_function(char c)
{
  fn_ptr_t result = 0;

  switch (c)
 {
    case 'a':
      result = a_fn;
      break;
    case 'b':
      result = b_fn;
      break;
 }

 return result;
}

int
main()
{
  fn_ptr_t fn = return_function('a');

  std::cout << "a(l) = " << (fn)('l') << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```