# Error in return a function pointer in C++ without typedef

Tags: c++, return, function-pointers

I'm trying to return a pointer to function without the use of typedef, but the compiler (gcc) is emitting a strange error, as if I could not do that kind of setting.

Remarks: With the use of typedef code works.

code:

```
void catch_and_return(void (*pf)(char*, char*, int&), char *name_one, char* name_two, int& number)(char*, char *, int&)
{
    pf(name_one, name_two, number);

    return pf;
}
```

Error:

'catch_and_return' declared as function returning a function

Can you explain to me why the compiler does not let me do this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the typedef code?  That will make it easier to understand what exactly it is you're trying to do.

Comment: this should be `void (*catch_and_return(void (*pf)(char*, char*, int&), char *name_one, char* name_two, int& number))(char*, char *, int&)` look at the answers on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997821/how-to-make-a-function-return-a-pointer-to-a-function-c) for some examples.

Comment: For the sake of your sanity, [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: Thank you, guys! The problem was solved. Carl Norum, the typedef code is: typedef void (*pf)(char*, char*, int&); 
pf catch_and_return(pf a, char *name_one, char *name_two, int& number)
{
    a(name_one, name_two, number);

    return a;
}

Comment: Perfectly valid question, should not get a minus. Best practice and theoretical "practice" questions are two different things guys.

Answer (score 7):

Declare your function as the following:

```
void (*catch_and_return(void (*pf)(char*, char*, int&), char *name_one, char* name_two, int& number))(char*, char *, int&)
{
    pf(name_one, name_two, number);

    return pf;
}
```

The syntax for functions that returns functions is:

*returned-function-return-type* (* *function-name* (*parameter-list*) ) (*function-to-return-parameter-list*)

**Note:** This declarations can be cumbersome to understand at first sight, use `typedef` whenever is possible

Comment: Thank you guy, yeah, I just wanted to know does not typedef

Comment: Where does the type of the function that is the argument go?

Comment: Before the function name (which is enclosed by parentheses): **type** `(*function-name)`(*parameters*)