# How function can return pointer to function that takes a function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I've read this question [How to make a function return a pointer to a function? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997821/how-to-make-a-function-return-a-pointer-to-a-function-c/997843#997843)

...but I am still having a problem. The `Index` function returns an enumerator function that takes a function to which it yields each index. The function signatures have been `typedef`ed in Indexer.hpp:

```
typedef bool (*yield)(Core::Index*);
typedef int (*enumerator)(yield);
```

...and the `Indexer` class

```
// Indexer.hpp
class Indexer {

    public:
        enumerator Index(FileMap*);

    private:
        int enumerate_indexes(yield);
};

// Indexer.cpp

enumerator Indexer::Index(FileMap* fMap) {
    m_fmap = fMap;
    // ...

    return enumerate_indexes;
}

int Indexer::enumerate_indexes(yield yield_to) {
    bool _continue = true;

    while(_continue) {
        Index idx = get_next_index();        
        _continue = yield_to(&idx);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler fails with the error below:

```
Indexer.cpp: In member function 'int (* Indexer::Index(FileMap*))(yield)':
Indexer.cpp:60:12: error: cannot convert 'Indexer::enumerate_indexes' from  
type 'int (Indexer::)(yield) {aka int (Indexer::)(bool (*)(Core::Index*))}' to  
type 'enumerator {aka int (*)(bool (*)(Core::Index*))}'
```

What am I missing in my declarations?

Comment: I have to ask .... why are you making life so difficult for yourself here? What's with all the function pointers?

Comment: A pointer to a non-member function is not the same as a pointer to a member function. The difference being that a pointer to a non-member function doesn't need an object to be called on, but a pointer to a member function does. I suggest you read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: Also you should know by now that we expect an [MCVE] here. You have a ton of unmentioned types in this snippet.

Comment: `enumerate_indexes` is not a function. It is a class method. Big difference. That's your problem. The correct answer depends on the details that are missing from the question, hence a [mcve] is required.

Comment: It seems I've found how to get it to compile. Thanks to @Someprogrammerdude for pointing me in the right direction with "pointer to a non-member function is not the same as a pointer to a member function."

I'll post my own answer as the *ton of unmentioned types* could just be `int`s or whatever and completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Indexer.hpp` the `typedef` needs to tell the compiler that `enumerator` is an `Indexer` member method:

```
typedef int (Indexer::*enumerator)(yield);
```

Now, other classes calling the `Indexer::Index(..)` is:

```
enumerator indexer = p_indexer->Index(&fmap);
indexer(do_something_with_index);

bool do_something_with_index(Index* idx) {
   return condition = true; // some conditional logic
}
```