# Returning a lambda function in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

```
typedef int (*identity_t)(int); 
identity_t retFun() { 
  return [](int x) { return x; };
}
```

This piece of code works, but why do I need the first line？

Why doesn't the code below work?

```
int (*)(int) retFun() { 
  return [](int x) { return x; };
}
```

Comment: Related: [How to make a function return a pointer to a function? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997821/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typedef makes it easier to write the function declaration, but you don't need the typedef if you know the right syntax:

```
int (*retFun())(int) {
    return [](int x) { return x; };
}
```

As you can see, the typedef not only makes it easier to write; it makes it easier to read as well.

Comment: Using `auto` would also make it easer to read while still avoiding the typedef: `auto retFun() -> int(*)(int) { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

C++ syntax inherited from C is weird,  counterintuitive and archaic. You need the typefef to cope with the fact.

```
int (*retFun())(int) { ... }
```

is frankly an unreadable mess.

The new crop of the C++ syntax alleviates the problem somewhat.

```
auto retFun () -> auto (*)(int) -> int { 
   return [](int x) { return x; };
}
```

The new syntax is written mostly left-to-right, as one would read it.

```
  auto retFun
```

"retFun is ..."

```
  () ->
```

"... a function that takes no arguments and returns ..."

```
  auto (*)
```

"... a pointer to ..."

```
  (int) ->
```

"... a function that takes an int argument and returns ..."

```
  int
```

"... an int".

[More about function declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function).

Comment: Frankly, I don't see why that C++ syntax is any better. Could you break it down piece by piece? Or link me to where I can read more about the new syntax?

Comment: Instead of "auto", can we use something in places where it appears?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's a syntax wart we're stuck with.